# How to enable ckeditor plugin in readonly mode?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I want to enable ckeditor ColorButton plugin when editor is in readonly mode. Below is the code which I have tried in console and is working fine

```
"CKEDITOR.instances["editor"].commands["bold"].enable()"
```

my console:
[image]

But instead of bold I want to enable colorbutton plugin I cannot find "colorbutton" inside my object

Comment: did you get any solution for it ? i also want a solution for this kind of functionality